# Выделение объекта по контуру

Tags: c#, unity3d

Какие есть способы выделения(либо подсветки, а еще лучше подсветки только контура) объекта в игре при наведении на него курсора. Если использовать компоненты гало или Light, то смотрится не очень хорошо.

Comment: Outline шейдер, в Unity из коробки его нет, но в интернете (хотя бы в том же вики по Unity) полно примеров.

Comment: я правильно понимаю: копируем материал и применяем к нему Outline шейдер ? А выделение заключается в смене материала из скрипта?

Comment: "копируем" здесь не совсем подходит, просто создаем материал с шейдером обводки. Нет, обычно подобный шейдер используется вместе с "основным шейдером". Просто добавляйте его к Rendererу, когда нужно сделать обводку и удаляйте, когда обводка ненужна, в данном случае полезно хранить ссылку на данный шейдер, чтобы не подгружать его каждый раз. Также можно в шейдере использовать boolвскую переменную, но это не очень эффективно, насколько я знаю.

Comment: недавно столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вот решение:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEth0drTuyg&t=33s&ab_channel=SpeedTutor